# I cannot connect to Gcloud instance using ssh, since cpu is 99.9% of use

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a gcloud vm instance of type custom (4 vCPUs, 8 GB memory), with ubuntu 16.04, 10Gb disk space. Today at specific time (7:30 am), start using the 99% of cpu. I restart the machine but continue to use the 99% of cpu. Now I cannot connect through ssh. There is any workaround to connect to my instance and see what the problem is?? Thank you!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably try to [connect through the serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#enabling_interactive_access_on_the_serial_console) :

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata INSTANCE --metadata serial-port-enable=1
gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port INSTANCE
```

Probably the tty on the serial port will be a lot less sensitive to the high CPU usage and you'll be able to log in.

Now, this will ask you for a user and password...what to do if you are (correctly) using only RSA Keypair authentication for ssh? Here there is a quick and dirty hack that does the job:

1 - Set up this as the [startup script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript) `echo "root:1234" | chpasswd` like this, for example:

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata INSTANCE --metadata startup-script='echo "root:1234" | chpasswd'
```

2 - Reboot the instance so the startup script is applied

3 - Log in through the serial port

```
gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port INSTANCE
```

4 - Use root as username and 1234 as password (or whatever you put in the script)

5 - Don't forget to disable serial port access when you don't need it anymore.

Comment: And to change the password :O

Comment: Well, root ssh access is  disabled by default, and you trust all the user connecting to your instance, don't you? ;-) anyway a more classy approach would be to use " passwd -l root ". This option disables a password by changing it to a value which matches no possible encrypted value, so the only way to become root is through sudo su - as before.

Comment: Thank you very much @Jordi !!, I was able to connect using serial port and finally resolve the issue. By the way, it happens because the boot hdd was out of space!! A programming small mistake.